# No. of ways to color n objects with k colors where the objects are arranged in circle

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I want to know the no. of ways in which i can color n number of items with k colors where the items are arranged in circle. The question can also be understood as the no. of ways to color a circular graph with n nodes using k colors. There is no restriction, all the nodes could be of same color or distinct. I need a formula to predict all the combinations.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics). What you describe is called a "necklace" if abc = bca = cab, and is called a "bracelet" if also abc = cba.

Comment: This link at [MSE meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions#13335) has several examples  by various users.